# Integration similar to consequences of Riemann lebesgue lemma

Tags: riemann-integration

Let $f\in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$. Define , for $n\in N$ b_n=$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)sinntdx$.
Which of the following statement are true?
a) $b_n\to 0$, as $n\to \infty$

b)$nb_n\to 0$, as $n\to \infty$
Please give me hint for option b)
I tried substitution method, as it value of f(-π)=f(π) were given then I could able to done it easily. But how to think without that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) is false without periodicity. Just take $f(x)=x$ and compute the integral using integration by parts. $(nb_n)$ does not converge in this case.

Comment: Thankyou sir, actually the answer of part b is shown True in NBHM answers key, so I was keep on trying to prove it:-(